# How to find the start date of week from a given date?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a concern is that I want from a given date to retrieve the start date of the week for example: 15/04/2015 So the beginning of the week will: 13/04/2015 (for me the beginning of the week is Monday).

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this :-)

```
Dim FirstDayInWeek, LastDayInWeek  As Variant
Dim dtmDate As Date
dtmDate = "15/04/2015"
```

The begin date of week:

```
FirstDayInWeek = dtmDate - Weekday(dtmDate, vbUseSystem) + 1
MsgBox FirstDayInWeek
```

The end date of Week

```
LastDayInWeek = dtmDate - Weekday(dtmDate, vbUseSystem) + 7
MsgBox LastDayInWeek
```

Comment: Satisfied ?  @user3714770

Answer (score 2):

Try this Formula:-

```
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1,2)+1
```

Where A1 contains your Input Date.