# Excel VBA - Week Ending Date

Tags: vba, excel

Column B is my data - if there is a date value in column B please return week ending date in column C. Need a VBA code to accomplish this

```
Column B      Column C

11/9/2016     11/11/2016
11/8/2016     11/11/2016
4/4/2017      4/7/2017
(blank)       (blank)
3/28/2017     3/31/2017
```

Below is all I could get, but it's not any good.

```
Dim FirstDayInWeek, LastDayInWeek  As Variant
Dim dtmDate As Date
dtmDate = Range("B2:B")
LastDayInWeek = dtmDate - Weekday(dtmDate, vbUseSystem) + 7
MsgBox LastDayInWeek
```

Comment: So you need the date of the **following Friday  ??**

Comment: Why VBA, when you can get it using formula?

Comment: Yes following Friday, also VBA because this will be part of a process that will be used repetitively. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

I replied to your comment on [how to find the start date of week from a given date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026572/how-to-find-the-start-date-of-week-from-a-given-date/43211263#comment73496566_43211263), but here it is as an answer:

```
Function ReturnDate(DateRange As Date, Optional DayInWeek = 1) As Date
    ReturnDate = DateRange - Weekday(DateRange, vbUseSystem) + DayInWeek
End Function
```

`=ReturnDate(A1)` gives Monday
`=ReturnDate(A1,2)` gives Tuesday
.
`=ReturnDate(A1,5)` gives Friday < --- This is the one you're after.
`=ReturnDate(A1,7)` gives Sunday.

A blank cell will give `01/01/1900`, but you could add a check for that or format the cell not to show 0.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I might add that the spreadsheet formula equivalent of this is (for cell C1):
    =B1+7-WEEKDAY(B1,16)

Answer (score 0):

Perhapse you could take an approach like the one below

```
Sub ReturnWeekEndDate()
    Dim InpRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set InpRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B5")

    For i = 1 To InpRng.Rows.Count
        If IsDate(InpRng.Cells(i, 1).Value) And IsDate(InpRng.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
            InpRng.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 2) = InpRng.Cells(i, 1).Value - Weekday(InpRng.Cells(i, 1).Value, vbUseSystem) + 7
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub INeedADate()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, r As Range, Bigr As Range

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        Set r = Cells(i, "B")
        If IsDate(r.Value) Then
            addy = r.Address
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Evaluate(addy & "-WEEKDAY(" & addy & ",3)+IF(WEEKDAY(" & addy & ",3)>4,11,4)")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is similar  to using the worksheet formula:

```
=B1-WEEKDAY(B1,3)+IF(WEEKDAY(B1,3)>4,11,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this...

```
Sub GetFridayDate()
Dim LastDayInWeek   As Date
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("B2:B" & lr)
For Each Cell In Rng
    If IsDate(Cell.Value) Then
        LastDayInWeek = Cell + 8 - Weekday(Cell, vbFriday)
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = LastDayInWeek
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that this would be part of a process...so, just call the function as I have shown, and you're golden!  BOOM!

```
Sub FindEndOfWeek_Test()
Call FindEndOfWeek(ActiveSheet, 1, 2, 6, 1)
End Sub

Function FindEndOfWeek(Sht As Worksheet, KnownDate_Column As Integer, _
                       EndOfWeek_Column, EndOfWeek As Integer, _
                       StartingRow As Long)
' This function takes in a spreadsheet, and and determines the date at the end
'   of the week, based on known parameters being passed into the function.
'

Dim a As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim EvalDate As Date
Dim NewDate As Date

' Determine the last row of the column you are working with
LastRow = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, KnownDate_Column).End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through your entire spreadsheet to determine the end of the week for all rows
For a = StartingRow To LastRow
    If IsDate(Sht.Cells(a, KnownDate_Column).Value) = True Then
        NewDate = Sht.Cells(a, KnownDate_Column).Value
        EvalDay = Weekday(NewDate)
        ' Determine the known date day of the week, and add accordingly.
        If EvalDay < EndOfWeek Then
            Sht.Cells(a, EndOfWeek_Column).Value = NewDate + (EndOfWeek - EvalDay)
        ElseIf EvalDay > EndOfWeek Then
            Sht.Cells(a, EndOfWeek_Column).Value = NewDate + (7 - EvalDay + EndOfWeek)
        Else
            Sht.Cells(a, EndOfWeek_Column).Value = NewDate
        End If
    End If
Next a

End Function
```

Comment: However, I REALLY should have implemented the one liner that Darren provided.  That was pretty straight forward and slick.  The only potential I see with Darren's is that if you call the day immediately following Friday (Saturday), you'll just get the previous Friday, and that wouldn't be correct...or so I'm thinking.

Comment: Yes, using Darren's method...  'ReturnDate("11/12/2016", 6)'  results in "11/11/2016", which I believe is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think no need for vba, you use below formula:

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2+(7-WEEKDAY(B2,16)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you really need VBA code for this problem, which I did, you can convert the excel formula into a one-line solution like so:

```
WeekendingDate = Date + 7 - WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Date + 7 - 6)
```