# I want to take average of multiple columns in MS Access through a query

Tags: ms-access

I have ratings of 6 touch points in 6 columns and want to present average of all 6 columns together. Sample data image is given below:

Data format sample:
[image]

The desired result should be grouped by Month in the first query and by week in the second query:

Desired result:
[image]

My month column is in text and Week column is as Date/Time

Please help.

Comment: Seems like a job for Excel.

Comment: Looks like need 2 aggregate GROUP BY queries.

Comment: Recommend not use apostrophe in data unless absolutely necessary, as in names. This can cause issue with SQL statements constructed in VBA. Can be dealt with but still recommend not using. It's certainly not essential in this case.

Comment: The above images are a sample only. The real data size currently is 6 Lakhs and growing. I have stored my data in an access table and want to fetch results out of it

Answer (score 0):

My query didn't work properly the first time because Access likes putting zeros by default so make sure you have actual blank values in your tables or the average function will think the zero is an observation. then open the query designer and enter something like:
[image]
For the weekly-query right click a variable to add a totals row then just group by week ending and choose average as the summary function for each touch point.  I prefer to get dates and convert to the last day of the week.  Here is one example of how to do that:

[How to find the start date of week from a given date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026572/how-to-find-the-start-date-of-week-from-a-given-date)

For the month-query group by month and year and use the average function again:
[image]
The important part is month([week ending]).  The rest is just formatting.
if you paste sql into the sql view of the designer access can usually reverse engineer a design view (after adjusting the variable and table names):
**weekly query sql:**
SELECT TouchPoints.[Week Ending], Avg(TouchPoints.Point1) AS [Touch Point 1], Avg(TouchPoints.Point2) AS [Touch Point 2], Avg(TouchPoints.Point3) AS [Touch Point 3], Avg(TouchPoints.Point4) AS [Touch Point 4], Avg(TouchPoints.Point5) AS [Touch Point 5], Avg(TouchPoints.Point6) AS [Touch Point 6]
FROM TouchPoints
GROUP BY TouchPoints.[Week Ending];
**monthly query sql:**
SELECT MonthName(Month([TouchPoints]![Week Ending])) & "'" & Year([TouchPoints]![Week Ending]) AS [Month], Avg(TouchPoints.Point1) AS [Touch Point 1], Avg(TouchPoints.Point2) AS [Touch Point 2], Avg(TouchPoints.Point3) AS [Touch Point 3], Avg(TouchPoints.Point4) AS [Touch Point 4], Avg(TouchPoints.Point5) AS [Touch Point 5], Avg(TouchPoints.Point6) AS [Touch Point 6]
FROM TouchPoints
GROUP BY MonthName(Month([TouchPoints]![Week Ending])) & "'" & Year([TouchPoints]![Week Ending]), Year([TouchPoints]![Week Ending]);